# Mouse not interacting well in new 16.04 installation

Tags: nautilus, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an old gaming computer and I got a weird issue. When the computer boots, the mouse does not interact well with the windows environment. It works fine on the side bar, but when I click on the windows nothing happens (for example, I can't close them or move them, and even clicking inside Firefox to navigate a webpage doesn't work). It's not the mouse, I tried two different ones, same outcome. A quick and dirty fix for me is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to move to another terminal, then go back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - this fixes it. I also found out it didn't happen one time in which I launched in recovery mode. The computer booted in 1024x768 though and didn't seem to recognize the full resolution of the screen that time.

Any ideas or tips?

EDIT:

output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                                  id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                        id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.3 Mouse                       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.1        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.1        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                                 id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                       id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                      id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                      id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony Saitek Cyborg Keyboard                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony Saitek Cyborg Keyboard                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.1        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

EDIT 2:

output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 Rev. 2] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 Rev. 2]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really a rodent expert but can you provide more information? When you first boot open a terminal with `<ctrl>` + `<alt>` + `T` and type `xinput list`. After fixing mouse with your band-aid approach repeat the listing. If they are different post both lists into your question. If the same post either list into your question. Also you didn't mention the *"full resolution"* is it 1920x1080? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 1920x1080, it's an HDMI connected screen btw. Will run that test, however I don't think it's a problem of recognition as, as I said, the mouse is definitely there - the cursor moves, and clicking on the side bar works. Only interaction with windows is broken.

Comment: Yes on second thought it is starting to sound like a problem with the windows manager. I've been lucky and not experience such behavior before but hopefully others have and can respond.

Comment: Finally tried it (sorry for the delay, it's not my main computer), and no difference between before and after.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Done. This was done after I used the fix, does it matter?

Comment: Perhaps `xinput` has nothing to do with Nvidia problems (@Pilot6 is the expert on that) but I notice your MS nano transceiver appears three times whilst my Logitech equivalent doesn't appear at all. Also your keyboard appears twice and your Power button appears twice, however the sleep button is missing. When compared to my list it seems wrong, it may be ok though.

Comment: ...actually, at the moment I made this log, I *may* have had two keyboards connected at the same time :D. However I tried removing one too and the problem wasn't fixed.

As for the transceiver: the keyboard is a Microsoft ergonomic model. I have the only-keyboard version, but there is also a keyboard+mouse version on the market that uses only one USB transceiver. I suspect that might be the reason for it appearing also under the pointer section.